# find if a list of list has items from another list

Tags: python, pandas

we have two list,

```
l=["a","b","c"]
s=[["a","b","c"],
["a","d","c"],
["a-B1","b","c"],
["a","e","c"],
["a_2","c"],
["a","d-2"],
["a-3","b","c-1-1","d"]]
print l 
print s
```

Now, I am try to see if each 2nd-level list of `s` has fuzzy match to any of items in list `l`.

```
matches=list() 
matchlist2=list()   
print s2
for i in range(len(s)):
    matches.append([])
    for j in range(len(s[i])):

        for x in l:
            if s[i][j].find(x)>=0:
                print s[i][j]
                matches[i].append(True)

                break
        else:
            matches[i].append(False)


    matchlist2.append(all(x for x in matches[i]))
print matches
print matchlist2
```

This gives me what was intended. But I am not happy with how it has so many loops. I am also working with pandas and if there is pandas solution that will be great to. In pandas, there are just two columns of two dataframes.

```
[[True, True, True], [True, False, True], [True, True, True], [True, False, True], [True, True], [True, False], [True, True, True, False]]
```

the second code checks if all items in sublist had match.

```
[True, False, True, False, True, False, False]
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com.  We are here for code that is *not* working.

Comment: in your case, what is defined as a fuzzy match?

Comment: On top of what @zondo said, take a look into recursion. It will reduce loop hierarchy and give you more power over multi-level arrays.

Comment: @zondo, great didn't even know there is codereview. @timgeb, by fuzzy match I meant not exact match but some part of the string like `a-B1` is match for `a`

Comment: @Ananta in that case, why is the output not a list that only consists of `True`? 'a' is in every sublist.

Comment: @timgeb, oops, a sublist however should have all trues, like you see on 2 lists on the end. I will edit the question now to make it clear.

Comment: "Now, I am try to see if each 2nd-level list of s has fuzzy match to any..." <- so you mean "to ALL" ?

Comment: Now, I am try to see if ALL of 2nd-level list of `s` has fuzzy match to ANY of `l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer this solution for conciseness and readability:

```
>>> [all(any(x.startswith(y) for y in l) for x in sub) for sub in s]
[True, False, True, False, True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this in a few lines using `map`, `filter` and lambda expressions:

```
matches = map(lambda b:[len(filter(lambda x:x in a,l))>0 for a in b],s)

matchlist2 = [all(a) for a in matches]
```

This expression `filter(lambda x:x in a,l)` returns all elements where a string in `l` is part of a string in `s`. The `len...>0` is then used to verify is at least one element is found. The final lambda (`lambda b`) is then used to get the `true` and `false` values for each element in `s`.

Comment: Thanks Jaco, great answer I still struggle using this "hacks"

Answer (score 0):

Check if each item is in the reference list:

```
[[e in l for e in sl] for sl in s]
```

Check if all items are in the reference list:

```
[all(e in l for e in sl) for sl in s]
```

Comment: thanks @arhimedec, however it is checking the whole match not partial match

Comment: Do you want to know whether ALL items matches… checking partially?!